# Initialize an array - MIPS

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

Hi I am pretty new in the world of assembly language (MIPS language). I am trying to create an array and to fill it with values that grow up ten by ten until a certain number, and after that to display it. For some reason, when I compile the program, I think it stops after the execution of sw, but I have no idea why the program doesn't run after this execution and display the content of the array.

Here is my code:

```
.data
arr: .space 3000

.text
main:
    la $t0, arr #to => Pointer to arr1
    li $t3, 50   #t3 => Nbr of type run through the loop ==> Max
    li $t6, 10   #t6 = Init value of 10
loop:
    slt $t4, $t5, $t3 #if t5 >= Max t5 = 0
    beq $t4, $zero, display
    
    sw $t6, 0($t0)
    addi $t0,$t0, 4 # Point to the next adress
    addi $t6, $t6,10 #Increment t6 by 10
    
    addi $t5, $t5, 1
    j loop
display:
    li $t5, 0 # Reset t5 to zero
    slt $t4, $t5, $t3
    beq $t4, $zero, end
     
    lw $t6, 0($t0)
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t6
    syscall 

    addi $t5, $t5, 1
end:    
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Did you try single stepping?  What do you see?

Comment: Yes I see that my program doesn't run after store execution

Comment: Ok, can you be more descriptive?  Does it stop with an error?  Does it inf. loop? ...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you want to create an array that holds numbers from [10,20,30... (array_max*10)]
Here is a working code for you. note that by change loop_max to any number you like you can resize the array dynamically without any further effort.
I also recommend using MARS for MIPS code editing/simulation and definitely use breakpoints to debug your code.

```
.data
arr: .space 3000

.text
.eqv loop_max 50        # represents: array size  & loop max

main:
    la $t0, arr     #to => Pointer to arr1
    li $t3, 0       #t3 => Nbr of type run through the loop ==> Max
    li $t6, 10      #t6 = Init value of 10

array_init_loop:
    beq $t3, loop_max, display
    sw $t6, 0($t0)
    addi $t0,$t0, 4     # Point to the next adress
    addi $t6, $t6,10        # Increment t6 by 10
    addi $t3, $t3, 1        # counter++
    j array_init_loop
    
display:
    li $t3, 0       # counter reset to 0
    la $t0, arr     # we have to load arr original address again because we altered it in the previous loop
    
    display_loop:
    beq $t3, loop_max, end
    # load next element from the array in a0 for print
    lw $a0, 0($t0)
    li $v0, 1       # v0 = 1 for printing integer
    syscall

    # print a space
    li $a0, 32      # 32 = space in ascii table
    li $v0, 11      # v0 = 11 for printing char
    syscall
    #########
    
    addi $t0, $t0, 4    # move to next word in the array (4 bytes)
    addi $t3, $t3, 1    # counter++
    j display_loop
    
end:    
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

running this outputs:

```
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170 180 190 200 210 220 230 240 250 260 270 280 290 300 310 320 330 340 350 360 370 380 390 400 410 420 430 440 450 460 470 480 490 500 
-- program is finished running --
```